# Java performance issue: Need to iterate more than 8 million records with a target-branch check

Tags: java, performance, function

We have a system that processes flat-file and (with a couple of validations only) inserts into database.

This code:

`//There can be 8 million lines-of-codes`

```
for(String line: lines){
   if (!Class.isBranchNoValid(validBranchNoArr, obj.branchNo)){
    continue;
   }
   list.add(line);
 }
```

definition of `isBranchNoValid`:

`//the array length ranges from 2 to 5 only`

```
public static boolean isBranchNoValid(String[] validBranchNoArr, String branchNo) {
  for (int i = 0; i < validBranchNoArr.length; i++) {
    if (validBranchNoArr[i].equals(branchNo)) {
        return true;
      }
       }
    return false;
    }
```

The validation is at line-level (we have to filter or skip the line that doesn't have a `branchNo` in the array). Earlier, this wasn't (filter) the case.

Now, high-performance degradation is troubling us.
I understand (may be, I am wrong) that this repeated function call is causing a lot of `stack` creation resulting in a very high `GC` invocation.

I can't figure out a way (is it even possible) to perform this filter without this high cost of performance degradation (a little difference is fine).

Comment: I don't understand the difference between "earlier" and now. What "wasn't the case" before? I also don't understand how the method actually checks the line, some it doesn't receive it as an argument.

Comment: are you saying that earlier you did not have this filter at all? and now it's causing performance issues? how do you know that this is specifically causing the issue?

Comment: If you're writing the data to a database, it would probably be faster if you just inserted all lines and then removed the unwanted ones via SQL.

Comment: @daniu "Earlier": We didn't have this filter before; we just inserted the line data (after basic validation) into database. Now, we need to filter out the lines based on the `branchNo`

Comment: @Eugene This is the only change that we made in our system (code). We are facing performance issues since then

Comment: @daniu We have considered this approach, but ignored (although we haven't executed) it since `Delete from some_table where branch_no IN (list_of_branchNo)` is an expensive operation, too. We plan to give this a shot once we exhaust out of options at code-level.

Comment: You have a class named "Class" ? You use a static method for this ? You looping for testing the match ? (you should use lookup in Map and you are done). Lot of code smell in a few lines. What I say not should generate any performance problem, but maybe the rest isn't better ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a stack problem for sure, because your function is not recursive  nothing is kept in the stack between calls; after each call the variables are erased since they are not needed anymore.

You can put the valid numbers in a set and use that one for some optimization but in your case I am not sure it will bring any benefits at all since you have at most 5 elements.

Comment: By `stack` I meant `function-stack`. Don't you think such a `stack` would be created every time this function is called (and destroyed when control exists the function)?

Answer (score 0):

So there are several possible bottlenecks in your scenario.

1. reading the lines of the file
2. Parse the line to construct the object to insert into the database
3. check the applicability of the object (ie branch no filter)
4. insert into the db

Generally, you'd say IO is the slowest, so 1. and 2. You're saying nothing except 2. changed, right? That is weird.

Anyway, if you want to optimize that, I wouldn't be passing the array around 8 million times, and I wouldn't iterate it every time either. Since your valid branches are known, create a `HashSet` from it - it has O(1) access.

```
Set<String> validBranches = Arrays.stream(branches)
                              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Then, iterate the lines

```
for (String line : lines) {
    YourObject obj = parse(line);
    if (validBranches.contains(obj.branchNo)) {
        writeToDb(obj);
    }
}
```

or, in the stream version

```
Files.lines(yourPath)
     .map(this::parse)
     .filter(o -> validBranches.contains(o.branchNo))
     .forEach(this::writeToDb);
```

I'd also check if it isn't more efficient to first collect a batch of objects, then write to db. Also, it's possible that handling the lines in parallel gains some speed, in case the parsing is time intensive.